# OneDrive for Business account not working with MS Graph SDK

Tags: android, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have implemented access to OneDrive files using the Graph SDK from https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android

For Authentication, I am using the same approach as in the [Connect sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/android-java-connect-sample) which uses the MSAL library, i.e. `compile ('com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:0.1.+')`in the build.gradle file.

I am calling `mPublicClientApp.acquireToken` with 
`String[] scopes = {"offline_access", "https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite","https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"};` and successfully retrieve accessTokens for both personal accounts and business accounts.

Next, I want to store a file on the user's OneDrive using

```
client.getDrive()
                .getRoot()
                .getItemWithPath("file.txt")
                .getContent()
                .buildRequest()
                .put(data);
```

which works as expected with a personal account but fails with `403: Forbidden` when using my business account (which BTW is the user of the app in the Azure portal). Similarly, I get `404: Not found` if I try to get the DriveItem for a file which does exist (and that works for the personal account as well).

Is there anything wrong with my code or does it look like wrong configuration of the app? (I am using the "preview mode" in Azure portal). The permissions I have added are

```
Files.ReadWrite

Delegiert

Have full access to user files

-
offline_access

Delegiert

Access user's data anytime

-
User.Read

Delegiert

Sign in and read user profile

-
User.ReadWrite

Delegiert

Read and write access to user profile

-
```

This is my full manifest (with some IDs removed):

```
{
    "id": "...",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "allowPublicClient": true,
    "appId": "...",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2018-12-24T08:51:51Z",
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [
        "api://..."
    ],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": null,
        "support": null,
        "privacy": null,
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "name": "...",
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2Permissions": [
        {
            "adminConsentDescription": "blub",
            "adminConsentDisplayName": "bla",
            "id": "d3659b01-433e-44eb-ab39-9ee9c19f7fe8",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "type": "User",
            "userConsentDescription": null,
            "userConsentDisplayName": "read files",
            "value": "Files.ReadWrite"
        }
    ],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": null,
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "publisherDomain": "crocoapps.onmicrosoft.com",
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient",
            "type": "InstalledClient"
        },
        {
            "url": "msal8374f.................d9b2://auth",
            "type": "InstalledClient"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf",
            "type": "InstalledClient"
        }
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5c28f0bf-8a70-41f1-8ab2-9032436ddb65",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "b4e74841-8e56-480b-be8b-910348b18b4c",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": null,
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `replyUrlsWithType` values aren't holding the correct values. This list should hold the URLs to which **Azure AD** will redirect to once a token is issued.

Taken from [Azure Active Directory app manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest):

> **replyUrlsWithType**
>
> This multi-value property holds the list of registered redirect_uri values that Azure AD will accept as destinations when returning tokens. Each uri value should contain an associated app type value. Supported type values are: `Web`, `InstalledClient`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for looking into this. The URIs in this list have been added as I checked the suggested Redirect URIs in the GUI config. I have checked those three because two were suggested in some articles which I read, but the msal-URI is actually the one which makes authentication work correctly. What do you think should be the correct value?

Comment: I didn't encounter those 2 URLs being used as redirects, so that section really popped out for me. As far as I remember, that list should contain URLs used to receive the token on your end.

Comment: well, "my end" is an android app and the msal-URI is acually registered in the app's manifest, so I think that should be fine, right? It also looks to me like the authentication is working (I do receive an access token), so I suspect it's rather something related to permissions?

Comment: Then maybe you're missing a scope for OneDrive for Business (I don't think they'll use the same scope for two different products)